# Every function $G \to \mathbb{C}$ that is constant on conjugacy classes is the character of some representation of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group. Every function $G \to \mathbb{C}$ that is constant on conjugacy
classes is the character of some representation of $G$.

This statement was said to be false, but intuitively I find it to be true. Can someone offer a counter example?

Comment: This is a somewhat uninteresting counterexample but if the function does not take algebraic integer values then it's not a character. And of course a character needs to take an integer value (the degree of the representation) in $e$.

Comment: Moreover (more interesting) it seems like another theorem of Burnside shows the existence of at least one zero in a character's values as soon as it is not of degree $1$. (I'll wait before making an answer out of these comments in case you want to change something about your hypothesis)

Comment: Another counterexample is the function that takes the value $-1$ on all elements of $G$.

Answer (score 3):

Every representation is a direct sum of irreducible representations. (Assuming Maschke's theorem applies, so the group's size is invertible in the field.) Thus, every character is a sum of irreducible characters. Every **virtual** character is a difference of two characters, and is some integer combination of irreducible characters. In this way, virtual characters are a **lattice** in the vector space of class functions. In particular, over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, this is a **discrete** subgroup, so is relatively "sparse" - all its elements are "isolated" from each other.

Consider the trivial group, for instance. It has exactly one representation in any dimension. Thus, if we identify the space of (say, real-valued, for simplicity) class functions with $\mathbb{R}$ itself, the characters correspond to the subset $\mathbb{N}$, and the virtual characters correspond to the subset $\mathbb{Z}$. Would you say the claim 'every real number is an integer' (or even 'is a whole number') to be an "intuitively true" claim? For a specific counterexample, consider any function which takes a non-integer value at the identity element: any character evaluated at the identity is the dimension of the representation, so any virtual character evaluates to an integer.

Or, consider real reps of the group $\mathbb{Z}_2$. The vector space of class functions we can identify with $\mathbb{R}^2$ (with the two coordinates being the function values on the two possible inputs). The irreps correspond to $(1,\pm1)$, so the virtual characters correspond to a "diamond grid" within the 2D plane, and the characters correspond to one "quadrant" of this grid.